# How to search the body of text by content type?

Tags: views, search

Is it possible to create a view where the user enters a text to query, and the view will only display results for certain content types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a search field called something like "Search: Search terms" which you can add as a filter criteria. Just expose it so the user can enter a search phrase.

Works only for indexed content, so make sure your index is at 100%.